# Why and when did "crack" come to mean "tell"?

Tags: etymology, word-usage

*Cracking jokes* is to me the most familiar contextual usage of this term.

Why would anyone say they were *cracking* jokes, not just *telling* jokes?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a difference between "Crack" and "Tell" when it comes to jokes.  To *crack a joke* is to make an **original witty remark** (i.e. something that, in context, is funny, but would not necessarily stand alone as humor); to *tell a joke* is to relate a bit of humor that is expected to be received well by your audience.

A sample of the difference:

Your friend says "Hey, did you hear this news story?  A bookie in Vegas was attacked by one of his customers."

You say "Wow, I guess they were really at odds with each other.  Baaahaha!"

You have just cracked a joke.  A small, lame pun-based joke, to be sure, but still.

Your friend says "How many mice does it take to screw in a light bulb?  Two, but how did they get into the lightbulb in the first place?"

Your friend has just told a joke.

Comment: I beg to differ - that cracked joke about the bookie in Vegas was kinda funny! +1

Comment: @Hellion: this is an interesting suggestion, but have you any source for it?  It’s certainly not the etymological source of this use of *crack*, and I’ve never been aware of it being observed in usage.

Answer (score 7):

According to the book [A etymological dictionary of the Scottish language](http://books.google.ca/books?id=-rgrAAAAMAAJ), published in 1887, it comes ultimately from the french word *craquer* (emphasis mine):

> To CRACK, Crak, V. n. 1. To talk boastingly.]
>
> Add, as sense
> 4. To talk idly, S.
>
> "To crack," to boast, Norfolk; to converse, A.Bor.
> Fr. craquer signifies to boast. Signifie aussi dans le style familier, Mentir, habler, se vanter mal-a-propos et faussement. Diet. Trev.
> From what is mentioned by Mr. Pinkerton, it might seem to have been immediately borrowed from the French. Speaking of a famous tree in the neighbourhood of the Luxembourg at Paris, he says; " I believe this was the genuine tree of Cracovia, so called by a pun, not from the Polish town, but from the **old word craquer, which signifies to gossip, as we say to crack jokes.** For here the politicians used to assemble, and sit like so many destinies, spinning the thread of nations on wheels of rotten wood." Recollections of Paris, i. 182.

Comment: +1 for an answer that actually includes some documentary evidence!  Also worth noting: according to the OED’s citations, this usage used to be more general, with phrases like *cracking words*, *cracking boast*, *cracking speeches*, etc, going back to the 14th century; only from about the 18th century is it particularly associated with jokes.

Comment: @PLL Yes, when I was investigating this I was surprised to discover the southern US derogatory term "cracker" came from the same source in the 18th century – the poor lawless wanderers of Virginia, Maryland, and the Carolinas were known for boasting.

Answer (score 4):

You will also see (especially in the UK and Ireland) "cracking on" for telling a story or speaking extendedly, and "enjoying the crack" for getting together with friends to talk. That one is often spelled "craic" but Wikipedia is insistent it came from English crack: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Craic.

Answer (score 0):

I would say that "crack" (in this context) is a FORM of telling, rather than "telling" itself.

You can "tell" a joke, with a straight face and a monotone and not get any laughs.

To make a joke funny, you need to "crack" it as you "tell" it. Think of cracking open a nut. Or popcorn "crackling" with butter over an open fire.

Answer (score 0):

The term 'crack' appears in many contexts where both quickness and accuracy are involved, such as 'crack shot' or 'crackerjack wit'.  I suspect it's an onomatopoeia thing due to the plosive 'k' sounds at both the beginning and end of the word sounding like the 'crack of a whip'.